# gcc / clang / msvc on Intel: why ucomiss for QNAN == QNAN (expected), but comiss for QNAN <= QNAN (unexpected)?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, clang, ieee-754

Sample code (t2.c):

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#if _MSC_VER && ! __clang__ /*&& ! __INTEL_COMPILER*/
#pragma fenv_access (on)
#else
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#endif

int main(void)
{
    volatile _Bool b;
    volatile float f = NAN;  // quiet NaN per C11

    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
//  b = f == f;  // leads to ucomiss (signals Invalid if operand is SNaN)
    b = f <= f;  // leads to comiss  (signals Invalid if operand is QNaN or SNaN)
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))
    {
        printf("FE_INVALID\n");
    }
    return b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Generated assembler code for `b = f <= f`:

`clang t2.c -std=c11 -ffp-model=strict -S`:

```
    callq   feclearexcept
    movss   44(%rsp), %xmm1                 # xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movss   44(%rsp), %xmm0                 # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    comiss  %xmm1, %xmm0
    setae   %al
    andb    $1, %al
    movb    %al, 51(%rsp)
    movl    $16, %ecx
    callq   fetestexcept
```

`gcc t2.c -std=c11 -S`:

```
    call    feclearexcept
    movss   -8(%rbp), %xmm1
    movss   -8(%rbp), %xmm0
    comiss  %xmm1, %xmm0
    setnb   %al
    movb    %al, -1(%rbp)
    movl    $1, %ecx
    call    fetestexcept
```

`cl t2.c /std:c11 /fp:strict /Za /Fa`:

```
    call    feclearexcept
; Line 18
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR f$[rsp]
    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR f$[rsp]
    comiss  xmm1, xmm0
    jb  SHORT $LN4@main
    mov DWORD PTR tv76[rsp], 1
    jmp SHORT $LN5@main
$LN4@main:
    mov DWORD PTR tv76[rsp], 0
$LN5@main:
    cmp DWORD PTR tv76[rsp], 0
    jne SHORT $LN6@main
    mov DWORD PTR tv78[rsp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN7@main
$LN6@main:
    mov DWORD PTR tv78[rsp], 1
$LN7@main:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR tv78[rsp]
    mov BYTE PTR b$[rsp], al
; Line 19
    mov ecx, 16
    call    fetestexcept
```

Note: Here both clang & gcc:

- are conforming implementations to version `201112` OR not conforming implementations but `__STDC__` has the definition of `1`
- conform to the specifications in the annex F (`__STDC_IEC_559__` has the definition of `1`)

Note: Description of `comiss` and `ucomiss`:

- `comiss` - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comiss
- `ucomiss` - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ucomiss

IEEE 754-2008, 5.11, p4 (emphasis added):

> Programs that explicitly take account of the possibility of *quiet NaN* operands may use the
> *unordered-quiet predicates in Table 5.3* which *do not signal such an invalid operation exception*.

[image: IEEE 754-2008, Table 5.3]

Here we see that unordered-quiet predicate `LT EQ` (`<=` is C) is in the Table 5.3, and, hence, `QNAN <= QNAN` shall not lead to an invalid operation exception. Do I miss something? Why for `QNAN <= QNAN` compilers generate `comiss` instead of `ucomiss`?

Tool versions:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) 10.2.0

$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1

$ cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29913 for x64
```

Comment: Why are you looking at table 5.3 and not 5.2? In C, == is quiet and < is signalling (see isless for something quiet).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks! So, it was a misunderstanding of IEEE 754-2008. Yes, `<=` is `compareSignalingLessEqual` unordered-signaling predicate (Table 5.2), which signals Invalid in case of QNAN.